# Why Laravel 7 Does not accept bootstrap effect? and shows error=>> "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding

Tags: node.js, laravel

At first, I run the command: **that install laravel package for the web.**

```
 composer require laravel/ui
```

Then we Write another command, that create log-in and registration view,

```
 php artisan ui:auth
```

and then I follow the other commands

```
php artisan ui bootstrap

php artisan ui vue

php artisan ui react
```

now when I run: php artisan ui bootstrap 
command it shown error=>please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding

Then I install the Nodejs setup from [https://nodejs.org/en/download/][1]

I also added the Environment variable path on my computer.

**Steps**:

press windows key => Type 'environment variabl' => press ok. => click on-environment variables => select path => edit => new => C:\Program Files\nodejs (according to your path) => ok

still when I run  `php artisan ui bootstrap`, it shows the same error,

**please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding**

Help me for this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run these commands after installing node.js and setting Environment,

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

the actual source is,

https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel/laravel-7-6-authentication-tutorial-login-register-password-reset-example/